# How to convert and use the GLSL mat2 type to its equivalent in RenderScript

Tags: matrix, glsl, renderscript

What is the equivalent conversion of the glsl [mat2](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)) type in Renderscript and how to use it?

I came to the conclusion that it may be [rs_matrix2x2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_value_types.html#android_rs:rs_matrix2x2), but I can't find any sample code about how to use it.

I 'm trying to convert the next GLSL snippet into RenderScript:

**GLSL:**

```
vec2 test(vec2 coord, float c, float s)
{
    mat2 m = mat2(c, -s, s, c);
    return m * coord;
}
```

**Rendercript**:

```
float2 test(float2 coord, float c, float s)
{
    //???? -> mat2 m = mat2(c, -s, s, c);
    return m * coord;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. In case is of any use to others, here is the conversion and usage based in the sample snipped in the question:

```
float2 test(float2 coord, float c, float s)
{
    rs_matrix2x2 m = {c, -s, s, c};
    return rsMatrixMultiply(&m, coord);
}
```